# Scripting Artboard Export with specific bit depths

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, script

I'm working on setting up a reusable template for some PNG avatars. Unfortunately, the different avatars have specific export requirements. Currently I'm using Save for Web to achieve these specific export requirements. Unfortunately this process is slow as it means I have to have each avatar in a separate file and can't utilize artboards which would be much faster for designing and modifying.

Here are the specific requirements for my exports: 
[image: Table of dimensions, Bit Depth, Color Mode, Alpha Channel, File Size, and iDatChunk]

I'm wondering if its possible to set up these files in artboards, and then use a script that exports the artboards with all of their proper settings. I'm familiar with iterating through artboards in scripts in a  general sense, but not familiar with exporting with scripts and don't know the limitations therein.

Comment: It's almost possible using [Image asset generator in PS CC](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Image-Assets-Functional-Spec). The closest I think you can get with asset generator is making one avatar layer at the size of 512 and giving the layer this name: `512x512 Avatar-512.png24, 440x440 Avatar-440.png32, 240x240 Avatar-160.png32, 160x160 Avatar-64.png32, 64x64 Avatar.png8, 50x50 Avatar-50.png32` - but there is not option to set stuff like max filesize...

Answer (score 1):

If you have Photoshop CC, then I think the new ***Export As*** functionality might work for you.  It allows you to export different artboards, and specify the bit depth and transparency on a per arboard basis.

In the example below, check the File Settings section (at the upper right corner), to see how I specified bit depth and transparency for each artboard independently.

[image]

You can click on the screen capture above to see in more detail.

The only potential problem I can envisage here is that you would have to set the bit depths and transparency settings each time you use *Export As*. The settings aren't saved in the Photoshop document.